# Как автоматически определять изменения по sshfs?

Tags: linux, debian, развертывание, sshfs

Я решил сделать pull deployment. С git-репозитория обновления отправляются в хранилище.
Все хосты подключаются к этому хранилищу через sshfs. Но как им узнать, что в хранилище было отправлено обновление?

В sshfs есть возможность отловить событие изменения папки?
Или надо делать периодические проверки на наличие обновления? Если да, то как это сделать оптимизированно? Файлов в хранилище много, измениться может любой.

Comment: вообще, конечно, rsync. // а sshfs тогда получается лишней тормозящей работу прослойкой.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin хм. если делать через rsync, тогда и правда sshfs не нужен.
вообще совет мне нравится, спасибо

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а как решить такую проблему: что если rsync скачает данные из хранилища ровно в тот момент, когда в него делается обновление. т.е. он скачает только часть обновления

Comment: это весьма обширная тема. задано по её поводу множество вопросов и написано множество ответов. см. в любимом поисковике: «rsync atomic copy».

Answer (score 1):

В git делаете хук, который пушит сообщение в Слак или Телеграм, в зависимости от того, что у вас там.

Answer (score -1):

Автоматически определить изменения невозможно. Надо делать переодические проверки.

Оптимизация может быть с помощью специального файла. Создаете в хранилище файл, который будет хранить время последнего изменения. Все участники должны соблюдать такое правило: обновлять этот файл после каждого изменения репозитория. Если используется ci/cd, тогда этот файл можно обновлять автоматически. Хостам нужно проверять изменение только одного этого файла.

Comment: Git прекрасно знает, где, когда, что, и каким образом поменялось. Нет необходимости заводить еще и какой-то там файл.

Comment: @gbg вы не поняли. в хранилище git-репозиторий не хранится, там хранятся артефакты сборки.